# I want to parse the following xml using tbxml, can anyone help me

Tags: ipad

```
<Menuname><title>Meal Type</title>
    <submenu><title>Starters</title></submenu>
    <submenu><title>soups</title>
<subsubmenu cuisine="American" popularity="5" difficulty="easy" quickmeal="Cookingtime(0-30 minutes)" >
<title>French Onion Soup</title>
<ingredients>
             2 teaspoons olive oil
             6 onions,thinly sliced
             1 teaspoon sugar
             3 cups water
             1/4 teaspoon salt
             1/4 teaspoon black pepper
             4 slices French bread,toasted
             1/4 cup shredded Gruyère cheese </ingredients>
<recipe>
             Heat oil in Dutch oven or large pot over medium-low heat. Add onions and sprinkle with sugar; cook, stirring frequently, until onions are deep brown.
             Add water, broth, salt, and pepper to pot; bring to boil, scraping up browned bits from bottom of pan. Reduce heat and simmer, covered, 20 minutes.
             Preheat broiler.
             Set 4 flameproof bowls on baking sheet. Ladle soup evenly into bowls. Float 1 slice of bread in each bowl and sprinkle with rounded tablespoon Gruyère. Broil about 5 inches from heat until cheese is melted, about 2 minutes. </recipe>

<FYI>The key to success with this classic soup is to cook the onions very slowly until they have a chance to caramelize, which turns them a deep mahogany color and ensures a rich flavor.</FYI>    

             </subsubmenu>
             </submenu>
    <submenu><title>Salads</title></submenu>
    <submenu><title>Breakfast</title></submenu>
    <submenu><title>Brunch</title></submenu>
    <submenu><title>Main Dishes</title></submenu>
    <submenu><title>Side Dishes</title></submenu>
    <submenu><title>Breads</title></submenu>
    <submenu><title>Desserts</title></submenu>
    <submenu><title>Drinks</title></submenu>
</Menuname>

<Menuname><title>Cuisine</title>
 <submenu><title>American Cuisine</title></submenu>
 <submenu><title>Asian Cuisine</title></submenu>
 <submenu><title>European Cuisine</title></submenu>
 <submenu><title>Britian Cuisine</title></submenu>
 <submenu><title>African Cuisine</title></submenu>
</Menuname>

<Menuname><title>Popularity</title>
    <submenu><title>1</title></submenu>
    <submenu><title>2</title></submenu>
    <submenu><title>3</title></submenu>
    <submenu><title>4</title></submenu>
    <submenu><title>5</title></submenu>
</Menuname>

<Menuname><title>Difficulty</title>
    <submenu><title>Easy</title></submenu>
    <submenu><title>Medium</title></submenu>
    <submenu><title>Hard</title></submenu>
</Menuname>

<Menuname><title>Quickmeals</title>
    <submenu><title>Cookingtime(0-30 minutes)</title></submenu>
    <submenu><title>Cookingtime(30-60 minutes)</title></submenu>
    <submenu><title>Cookingtime(1-2 hours)</title></submenu>
</Menuname>


</Menus>
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried already?

Have you read the [guides](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/Guides.html) and the [API reference](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/API.html)?

In general I think you start with creating an TBXML object:

```
TBXML * tbxml = [[TBXML alloc] initWithXMLFile:@"books.xml"];
```

and then you can get its root element:

```
TBXMLElement root = tbxml.rootXMLElement;
```

and then query it for various things:

```
TBXMLElement * menuname = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"Menuname" parentElement:root];
TBXMLElement * menutTitle = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"title" parentElement:menuname];
NSString *titleString = [TBXML textForElement:menuTitle];
```

I worked this out by reading the documentation. If you've read the documentation and not understood it, it's helpful to post the bits that you didn't understand (to let responses be more specific). If you haven't read the documentation, you should really do so before posting on Stack Overflow!